# MySQL time between days

Tags: sql, mysql

I have an application storing the times a restaurant is open:

My code to get the currently open restaurants. My SQL query (simplified) looks like

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `restaurants` r 
 WHERE r.from <= NOW()  
   AND r.to >= NOW();
```

The problem here is, there's an entry which rolls over -- it's for a restaurant open from 11 AM to 3 AM the next day.

What would be a good query to capture that particular restaurant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In pseudo code:

```
if (close > open) {
    store_is_open = (open <= now <= close)
} else {
    store_is_open = (open <= now || now <= close)
}
```

Converting that to SQL:

```
WHERE IF(
    r.from < r.to,
    NOW() BETWEEN r.from AND r.to,
    NOW() >= r.from OR NOW() <= r.to
)
```

You might also want to check for places which are open 24 hours. The below code assumes that you would set the `from` and `to` times to be the same (eg: from midnight to midnight)

```
WHERE IF(
    r.from = r.to,
    1,
    IF(
        r.from < r.to,
        NOW() BETWEEN r.from AND r.to,
        NOW() >= r.from OR NOW() <= r.to
    )
)
```

Comment: Nice one.  Far simpler than my attempt.

Answer (score 0):

i understand from the question, that the dates is save in DB in datetime type,(you use NOW() function)

so try to use :

```
SELECT * FROM `restaurants` r WHERE r.from <= NOW() 
AND r.to >=DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

so its cover also this restaurants that close in the next day

Comment: I assume he's only storing times, not dates.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most efficient way to do it, but it does give the results you're looking for...

I'm guessing your `to` and `from` are `TIME` columns.  Since comparison of `TIME`s can't figure for a date difference, you'll want to change them into dates before comparing them:

```
SELECT *,
DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DATE_FORMAT(r.from, '%H:%i') HOUR_MINUTE) AS from_date,
IF (r.to > r.from,
    DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DATE_FORMAT(r.to, '%H:%i') HOUR_MINUTE),
    DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DATE_FORMAT(r.to, '+1 %H:%i') DAY_MINUTE)
) AS to_date
FROM restaurants r
HAVING NOW() BETWEEN from_date AND to_date;
```

The reason for the inefficiency is that MySQL has to go through the whole table to figure out all the from_date and to_dates and THEN check the `HAVING` comparison (`HAVING` allows for conditions on computed columns).